# Where are the sources for jsf-impl.jar 1.1 and jsf-api.jar 1.1 located?

Tags: jsf, jsf-1.1

Does anyone know where I can get the source code for jsf-impl.jar 1.1 and jsf-api.jar 1.1?

I am facing a tricky issue. I am getting an exception in code, and I would really like to see the source.

Grae

Comment: @BalusC A: 1.1_02 may be new enough, worth a shot.  The newest I could find was 1.2. Do you have a link? B: I worried about upgrading to 1.2, because it might break something else.  I found a post of yours saying that 1.2 100% backward compatible, but I am still a little worried about such a major shift.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1.1 (and 1.1_01) source is nowhere available on Internet as it was initially not open source, [1.1_02 source however is available on Internet](https://java.net/downloads/javaserverfaces/release/1.1/1.1_02/source/).

That said, are you well aware that 1.1 is so full of bugs and that a 1.1 app is fully forward compatible with 1.2, so you'd better just upgrade to latest 1.2 which is 1.2_15. Only if you were relying on specific 1.1 bug(s) being the correct behavior, then things may indeed seem to break. You'd better move forward instead of keeping sitting on EOL libraries.

Answer (score 2):

Try on : The Java community process site => JSR127 : Javaserver Faces => Community => Community files (or https://jcp.org/en/egc/egcfiles?id=127 , in short). You can download : 
jsf-20040513-1_1.zip
jsf-api-src-1_1.zip
jsf-ri-src-1_1.zip
JSF_20040513.pdf
(an "usual" mix of *.java, *.lib & sources). I'm trying to stabilize an old jsf-1.1 + Java Studio Creator + maven project ...
Ciao (best regards),
     Davide Grandi

PS : try also https://java.net/downloads/javaserverfaces/stable : 3 *.class files, execute it to decompress

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: Q: Where are the sources for jsf-impl.jar 1.1 and jsf-api.jar 1.1 located? A : https://jcp.org/en/egc/egcfiles?id=127 , 4 files among which jsf-api-src-1_1.zip jsf-ri-src-1_1.zip. It's my first post, am I missing some points, maybe ?

Comment: Upvoted because I was specifically looking for 1.1_01 src.
The three class files mentioned by Davide unzip to the jsf 1.1_01 src, just run them as main class in the folder where you downloaded them like this: > java javaserverfaces_source_1_1_01