# How do you control what java code is produced by a jsf 1.1 tag? (Not subjective!!)

Tags: jsp, jsf, jsf-1.1

JSF tags get "compiled" into java code.  How can I change the output, the java code, of a tag?

Where is the template for what gets written to the java source.  Here is an example.

```
<f:view>
```

Translates to:

```
  //  f:view
  com.sun.faces.taglib.jsf_core.ViewTag _jspx_th_f_005fview_005f0 = (com.sun.faces.taglib.jsf_core.ViewTag) _005fjspx_005ftagPool_005ff_005fview.get(com.sun.faces.taglib.jsf_core.ViewTag.class);
  _jspx_th_f_005fview_005f0.setPageContext(_jspx_page_context);
  _jspx_th_f_005fview_005f0.setParent(null);
  int _jspx_eval_f_005fview_005f0 = _jspx_th_f_005fview_005f0.doStartTag();
  if (_jspx_eval_f_005fview_005f0 != javax.servlet.jsp.tagext.Tag.SKIP_BODY) {
    if (_jspx_eval_f_005fview_005f0 != javax.servlet.jsp.tagext.Tag.EVAL_BODY_INCLUDE) {
      out = _jspx_page_context.pushBody();
      _jspx_th_f_005fview_005f0.setBodyContent((javax.servlet.jsp.tagext.BodyContent) out);
      _jspx_th_f_005fview_005f0.doInitBody();
    }
    do {
```

So all this code seems reasonable, but I need to change it.  Where is the source for this?  I am assume it is in jsf-api or jsf-impl, but have not found it.

Edit:
I added jsp tag. I think basic tag to java process must be related.

Comment: Basically, I gave up.  For more information, see http://book.javanb.com/servlets-and-javaserver-pages-the-j2ee_technology-web-tier/0321136497_ch07lev1sec7.html. 
Particularly, there are Tag types.  I think the type controls the output, not some custom tag code.

Comment: [As already stated](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27863304/1391249), the source is not available on the internet. Besides that is there any mandatory requirement that still makes you use JSF 1.1 - just as a curiosity?

Comment: @Tiny I am thinking about switching up to 1.2.  However, there is a reason I am reluctant.  We use custom components that were supposed to be compatible with jsf 1.1 and myfaces 1.2.  I have some doubts whether they will be compatible.  I have no idea whether they "were relying on specific 1.1 bug(s) being the correct behavior."  (From quoted answer.)  It is basically a regression issue.